# Hibernate - Abstract model with primary key leads to "Field '...' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: jpa, model, annotations, abstract, persist

I am new to the usage of Hibernate and have the following problem:

I created an abstract class which should hold the primary key for subclasses. The class looks as followed:

```
@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("PersistenceUnitPresent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstrHibernateModel
        implements IModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    protected long id;

    protected AbstrHibernateModel() {
        //
    }

    /* @param id */
    protected AbstrHibernateModel(final long id) {

        this.id = id;
    }

    /* @return */
    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    /* @param id */
    @Override
    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Then I have multiple subclasses with their own fields - important to me is that I do not need to create the primary key for every model itself. The subclasses mostly look like this:

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "country")
@javax.persistence.Entity
@com.imnos.core.database.model.HibernateModel(priority = 497L)
public class Country
        extends com.imnos.core.database.model.abstr.AbstrHibernateModel {

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "country_code")
    private java.lang.String countryCode;   
    @javax.persistence.Column
    private java.lang.String name;
    @javax.persistence.MapsId
    @javax.persistence.ManyToOne
    @javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private com.imnos.trader.core.database.model.Currency currency;

    /* Empty default constructor. */
    public Country() {
        //
    }    
    /* Auto generated constructor.
     *
     * @param countryCode
     * @param name
     * @param currency */
    public Country(
            final java.lang.String countryCode,
            final java.lang.String name,
            final com.imnos.trader.core.database.model.Currency currency
    ) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.name = name;
        this.currency = currency;
    }    
    /* @return */
    public java.lang.String getCountryCode() {
        return this.countryCode;
    }    
    /* @param countryCode */
    public void setCountryCode(final java.lang.String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }    
    /* @return */
    public java.lang.String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }    
    /* @param name */
    public void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
    /* @return */
    public com.imnos.trader.core.database.model.Currency getCurrency() {
        return this.currency;
    }    
    /* @param currency */
    public void setCurrency(final com.imnos.trader.core.database.model.Currency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }    
}
```

When saving the County model to the HibernateSession with a new Currency model (also saved to the HibernateSession before) and then commit my creations I get the follwing error:

```
16:39:35.859 [Thread-1] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Field 'currency_id' doesn't have a default value
16:39:35.862 [Thread-1] ERROR org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement]
[ERR][1528987175875][c.i.t.s.c.s.InitialSetupComponent] Unable to insertData().
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:494)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3245)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2451)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at com.imnos.trader.server.core.setup.InitialSetupComponent.insertData(InitialSetupComponent.java:277)
    at com.imnos.trader.server.core.setup.InitialSetupComponent.runSetup(InitialSetupComponent.java:303)
    at com.imnos.core.console.command.impl.CMDSetup.execute(CMDSetup.java:38)
    at com.imnos.core.console.abstr.AbstrConsoleComponent.handleInput(AbstrConsoleComponent.java:273)
    at com.imnos.core.console.abstr.AbstrConsoleComponent.lambda$run$1(AbstrConsoleComponent.java:372)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As far as I know everything went fine when the subclasses had their own id-field. Is it possible that I made a mistake in the case of inheritance in Hibernate? I also have seen the annotation @MappedSuperclass multiple times but I dont know whats the technical difference to the mentioned annotations in my abstract class. It also does not work when adding the models to Hibernates configuration.

Do you guys have any solutions or suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: Okay so I found out that this error occurs everytime I add a model to another model. Both get the same id. In my case the first created country gets the same id as the last currency and I dont know why.